# Correct recursive chmod, separate for files & dirs

Tags: linux, permissions, web, chmod

I'd like to recursively chmod a directory so that:

- Files are 0664
- Directories are 0775

How to do it better, shorter, fancier? :) Maybe, use umask somehow?

All `find` solutions are too long: I always end with Copy-Paste :)

Comment: I'm thinking a `find`, specifying either directory or file flags, with an -exec to `chmod`...

Comment: what do you mean by all find solutions are too long ?

Comment: Too long for being 'handy' to type at once :)

Comment: If you're doing this so frequently that you can't be subjected to the numbing repetition of the few extra characters of a simple `find`, it begs the question: why not fix the permissions via `umask` (or some program-specific option) so that they're correct in the first place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on your version of chmod, you may be able to do this:

```
chmod -R . ug+rwX,o+rX,o-w
```

Note the *capital* X.  This sets the executable bit on directories and files that already have any of the execute bit already set.

Note that you can only use capital X with '+', not '=' or '-'.

Comment: This option is in the POSIX standard, right?

Comment: At least it works in Linux :)

Comment: not working for me even on linux. `chmod -R ug+rwX,o+rX,o-w .` would have worked.

Answer (score 8):

Better, shorter, fancier than what ?

```
cd /directory
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +
find . -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

Comment: aaaw you beat me to it :(

Comment: Dangerous with files whose names contain certain reserved characters (like spaces, depending on your version of `find`).  Consider `-print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: @BMDan: strange as it may seem - it's safe with spaces - I tested it.

Comment: @Iain: I recently discovered this behavior, but I'm not insignificantly baffled by it, and I'm pretty sure `find` hasn't always worked this way.  Thus, my "depending on your version" disclaimer.

Comment: @BMDan in the event that find broke up any filenames with spaces (Which I run in to all the time) how would you use -print0 to fix it in this particular situation?

Comment: @Safado: `find . type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755` and `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'm assuming the -0 in xargs is required to prevent the same behavior? And I'm guessing using -print0 will still allow for the use of -exec (instead of piping to xargs)?

Answer (score 4):

Adding a oneliner to the mix

```
find -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} + -o -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find /dir -type f -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 0644
find /dir -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 0775
```

Test it before use it in real environment

Answer (score 1):

I am using this for anything copied from FAT filesystems:

```
chmod -R a-x+X .
```

If it does not work, for example on Mac OS X, try the GNU version of the command `chmod`:

```
gchmod -R a-x+X .
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. However, useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about why you're trying to do this, the most common reasons people tend to use are either:

- Files and directories are other-writeable

  `chmod -R o-w /path/to/dir`
- Files and directories are not group-writeable

  `chmod -R g+w /path/to/dir`

Or, combine the two:

```
chmod -R o-w,g+w /path/to/dir
```

Alternately, if you want files and directories to the correct permissions by default, modify the creating process's `umask`.

Basically, it's a rare day that it's correct to use numeric modes with `chmod`; typically, directories already have the executable bit set and files that don't need it lack it, so why muck around with it at all when the `+` and `-` operators obviate the need to do so?